# how to direct to the link via .tabsetpill

Tags: r, r-markdown, htmltools

I would like to direct to the relevant link when I click on the `.tabsetpill` is there any way to get around this? Many thanks in advance.

```
   ---
title: ""
output: html_document
---

# Quarterly Results {.tabset .tabset-fade  .tabset-pills}

## [Caret CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf){target="_blank"}
content is nothing.

## Second Tab
Here is the second tab's content
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to follow the link by clicking any tab?

Comment: I want to follow the link when I click on the .tabpill which I call Caret Cran but It does not direct me to link.

Comment: Seyma, I didn't hear about this opportunity. Maybe make a simple anchor tag inside the tab?